# how to check if "true or false = expanded area?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following list in bootstrap

```
<i class="fa fa-plus rgh-i" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#field-1"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus rgh-i" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#field-2"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus rgh-i" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#field-3"></i>
```

I use bootstrap to toggle a div.

Each element html `i` has a `aria-expanded="true"` when I want to show my div and `aria-expanded="false"` when I want to hide my div.

I want to check if there are already elements that `aria-expanded="true"`..and whether there next to hide the previous open.

```
$( "i" ).on( "click", function() {
        if(There are elements of that property aria-expanded="true")
       {
        hide previous item before you open the current one
       }else{
        //something
       }
});
```

I tried to make an example jsdfiddle but unfortunately we did ... I hope that you have understood what I want to do.

Basically ... I briefly before hiding the previous item to display the next and not be allowed to be open more than one element.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to make accordion.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(this.attr('aria-expanded') === "true"){
     // hide previous item before you open the current one
}
```

Comment: Please kindly give some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value

```
var areaexpandedtrue = $('[aria-expanded=true]');
if(areaexpandedtrue.length){
   areaexpandedtrue.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the value first, and then compare.

```
var value = $('#aria-expanded').val(); // jQuery func.

if (value =='true'){
//do some stuff
}
else{
//do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make accordion in bootstrap then try this.

```html
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Accordion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bs-example{
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

you can write your code by referencing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="test fa fa-plus rgh-i" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#field-1"></i>
```

This jquery call returns boolean if aria-expanded is true or false, if you use a jquery onclick you can pass the first parameter as `this`.

```
$('.test').attr('aria-expanded');

    $( ".test" ).click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded')) {
        //your code here
    } else {
        //your code here
    }
});
```